# How can I simultaneously read/write form a text file using C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file

I have multiple servers created.Each one has to send some data to its own client. I am using TCP/IP protocol. To prevent any data loss due to client getting disconnected, I am using a text file as a buffer. So in the program , there is a thread for each server which keeps on checking if the client is connected or not. If it is connected then it reads from the buffer and sends it to client. whenever some new data has to be send to client , I am first checking if client is connected.If client isn't connected then I am writing data to the same buffer text file. The problem I am facing is that I am unable to write to the file while thread is reading from it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public class TcpIp
    {
        public int machinePort;
        public static int port1 = 1024;
        public static int count = 0;
        public string bufferName;
        FileStream buffer;
        Socket client;
        public IPAddress localIp;
        public TcpListener sender;
        StreamReader reader ;
        FileStream iStream;

        //this.get
        public TcpIp(string id)
        {
            this.machinePort = port1 + count;
            while (!isAvailable(this.machinePort))
            {
                count++;
                this.machinePort = port1 + count;
            }
            this.bufferName = WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.path + "machine_" + id + ".txt";

            buffer = new FileStream(this.bufferName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            localIp = IPAddress.Parse(WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.ip);
            sender = new TcpListener(localIp, this.machinePort);

          // this.oStream = new FileStream(this.bufferName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
           //this.iStream = new FileStream(this.bufferName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
          // reader = new StreamReader(this.iStream);
        }

        bool isAvailable(int port)
        {
            bool isAvailable = true;
            IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

            foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
            {
                if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port == port)
                {
                    isAvailable = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return isAvailable;
        }

        public void createServer()
        {
                this.sender.Start();
                string line;
                reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
                //client = sender.AcceptSocket();
                while (true)
                {

                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (!connected())
                    {
                        client = sender.AcceptSocket();
                    }

                    while (reader.EndOfStream && line != null)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
                        client.Send(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                   // iStream.Flush();    
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    //reader = new StreamReader(iStream);
                }
        }

        public void writeToClient(string data)
        {
            if (connected())
            {
                //send data to client
                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                //System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                this.client.Send(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            else
            {
                //write to file
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(this.bufferName);
                        sw.WriteLine(data);
                        sw.Close();
                        break;           
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("WaitForFile {0} failed to get an exclusive lock: "+ex.Message );
                        // Wait for the lock to be released
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        bool connected()
        {
            if (client == null)
                return false;
            else 
                return client.Connected;
        }
    }
}
```

Any enlightenment would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Where are your threads? I could not find any Threads created in the above code?

Comment: Do multiple clients write to the same text file? or does each client have his own file?

Comment: The whole code is a bit long. That's why i didn't post the code for threads.text file is separate for each client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is that you mix up access to the file.

You open a stream by `buffer = new FileStream(this.bufferName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);` in order to create a `StreamReader` from the opened stream for later reading by `reader = new StreamReader(buffer);`.

OTOH, you want get a `StreamWriter` for writing to the file by `StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(this.bufferName);`. This tries to open the file again which fails because of mismatching file sharing mode.

So you need to access the file for writing and reading via the very same "handle" (here FileStream). Furthermore, don't forget to serialize access by some locking mechanism in order to make it thread-safe. Otherwise, you'll get corrupted data. You'll probably need to maintain the read/write pointer (Stream.Position).

Answer (score 1):

You can't read and write from the same text file at the same time.

If you really want to use text files, why not using 2 of them:
One to read from and one to write into.
Once the read file is empty -> the read file is your new write file and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds logic, it's not possible for 2 threads to access a file as the same time, because the file is in use.

Imagine that it's even possible, you will have some very strange behaviour.

Why are you not using a lock() to make sure that only a single thread can access the file at a given time?

And with async programming, you don't need to wait until the lock is released before continueing your program.

Comment: the file for each thread is different.I just need solution for one thread.

Comment: If you are using a single thread, you need to make sure that the file is closed before reading from it or vice versa. If I'm correct, you're trying to read and at the same time write? that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create Threads like this

```
Thread thread = new Thread(yourMethod());
```

When you have multiple threads then what you need is ReaderWriterLockSlim. Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

It lets you to read a file by multiple threads but write the file with one Thread. I think this will solve your problem.